# Can't be called doPost function by shared users in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Now, I'm creating a mail sending application with Google Apps Script in my Google Spreadsheet.
This app do following actions.

1. Add a menu to call this application when the spreadsheet is opened.
2. Display UI to input mail subject when the menu is clicked.
3. Send mails to each addresses contained in the spreadsheet when submit button push by the spreadsheet opend user.

### Problem

The app work fine when i use.
But the other users who can edit the spreadsheet can not send emails (display ui is ok).

From dubug logs, I've found that the **doPost** function is not called.

Please tell me what is the problem.

### Program

```js
/*
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 * 
 * create custome menu in active spreadsheet
 */
function onOpen(e) {
  Logger.log("onOpen called");

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [
    {name: "MailSendApp", functionName: "displayAppUi"}    
  ];
  sheet.addMenu("CustomAppMenu", menuEntries);
}

/*
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 *
 * display ui
 */
function displayAppUi() {
  Logger.log("displayAppUi called");

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var formPanel = app.createFormPanel().setId('form').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
  var scrollPanel = app.createScrollPanel();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var appLabel = app.createLabel("Sendmails SpreadSheet App");
  var subjectLabel = app.createLabel("Subject");
  var subjectTextBox = app.createTextBox().setName("subject");
  var bodyLabel = app.createLabel("Body");
  var bodyTextArea = app.createTextArea().setName("body");
  var attachFile = app.createFileUpload().setName('attachFile');
  var sendBtn = app.createSubmitButton().setText("Send ALL");
  var sheetName = app.createHidden("sheetName", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName());

  // set client handler
  var submitClientHandler = app.createClientHandler()
    .forEventSource().setEnabled(false)
    .forEventSource().setText("Sending...");
  sendBtn.addClickHandler(submitClientHandler)

  // set sytles
  app.setWidth(800);
  app.setHeight(400);
  panel.setStyleAttributes({width: "100%"});
  appLabel.setStyleAttributes({color: "green", fontSize: "2em" });
  subjectTextBox.setStyleAttributes({width: "100%"});
  bodyTextArea.setHeight("240");
  bodyTextArea.setWidth("780");
  scrollPanel.setHeight("380");
  scrollPanel.setWidth("800");

  panel.add(appLabel)
       .add(subjectLabel)
       .add(subjectTextBox)
       .add(bodyLabel)
       .add(bodyTextArea)
       .add(attachFile)
       .add(sheetName)
       .add(sendBtn);
  scrollPanel.add(panel)
  formPanel.add(scrollPanel);
  app.add(formPanel);

  sheet.show(app);
}

/*
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 * 
 * handler to send emails to addresses in active sheet with input subject & body.
 */
function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log("doPost called");

  var param = e.parameter;
  var subject = param.subject;
  var body = param.body;
  var attachFile = param.attachFile;
  var sheetName = param.sheetName;
  var mailOptions = {};
  var mailAttachments = []

  // set attachment file if exists
  if (attachFile != null) {
    mailAttachments.push({
      fileName: attachFile.getName(),
      mimeType: attachFile.getContentType(),
      content: attachFile.getBytes()
    });
  }
  mailOptions["attachments"] = mailAttachments;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var emails = _collectEmailAddresses(sheet);
  for(var i=0; i < emails.length; i++) {
    var email = emails[i];
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, mailOptions);
  }

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();  
  return app;
}

/*
 * collect Email addresses from the argument sheet
 */
function _collectEmailAddresses(sheet) {
  var emails = [];
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  // get skip row numbers(that is header row num) from property
  var header_rownum = parseInt(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("header_rownum"));
  for (var i = header_rownum; i < range.getLastRow(); i++) {
    var email = values[i][1];
    emails.push(email);
  }
  return emails;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `openByID` instead of `.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName)` in your `doPost` trigger.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(_spreadsheetId);
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(_sheetName);
```